# Bluetooth remote connection with Android

Tags: android

I'm attempting to implement this application wrote by this guy here

http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/

I managed to compile the .apk and also the server in .jar. I run the server in my pc, already make the pc discoverable. i run the apps on the phone and manage to search for the available bluetooth device in the network. but when i try to connect, it say that unable to connect to device, any idea where i should look into next?

Answer (score 0):

Obvious, but still!
Have you checked that server bluetooth device on your PC is *discoverable*(visible in Bluetooth)?

Also, you can pair the 2 devices using their **default** software(this will simplify your first connection attempts, eliminating the pairing).